# Error :If ngModel is used within a form tag, either name attribute must be set or the form. control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions

Tags: angular

```
<form #employeeForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="dept21">Department2</label><br>
    <select 
      id="dept21" 
      name="dept21" 
      [(ngModel)]="dept21" 
      class="form-control">
      <option 
        *ngFor="let d of dept2" 
        [value]="d?.id">
        {{d.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have added name attribute. Still getting the error.

Comment: Try breaking the current serving app and run `ng serve` again.

Comment: restart your app after clearning cache, `npm cache clean -f`

Comment: Tried both commands . Still getting the same error in  <option 
        *ngFor="let d of dept2" 
        [value]="d?.id">

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfectly fine to me.

Try pressing `Ctrl + C`(on Windows) or `Cmd + C`(on Mac) to break the currently serving app.

And then run `ng serve` again.

That should fix it.

Comment: Still getting the same error . <option 
        *ngFor="let d of dept2" 
        [value]="d?.id">

Comment: Strange. Looks like you have more fields in the form which you haven't added in the OP. Would it be possible for you to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular).

Comment: Got it right .The name attribute was missing in some other div  tag . But dev tools showed error in this div .

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache and try to restart your app. Even if by doing that, it will not resolve your issue then you can simply add ***[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"*** in your select tag and It will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I simply added the name attribute inside the given HTML element.
For example: I faced this error after adding  as following:

```
<select id="inputLocationType" class="form-control custom-select" title={{tooltipMsg}} [(ngModel)]="locationType"  (change)="changeLocationType($event)">
```

Then I added the name attribute

```
<select id="inputLocationType" class="form-control custom-select" title={{tooltipMsg}} [(ngModel)]="locationType" name="location-type" (change)="changeLocationType($event)">
```

it worked